# Error when using with annotation Mixins with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, mixins

I am trying to create a mixin for one of my POJO's, with this code:

```
interface CustomerStatsIgnoreMixIn {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"ref"});
}

public class CustomerStatsJob extends Job {
    private void updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Customer.class,
                CustomerStatsIgnoreMixIn.class);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the follow error in Eclipse on the line `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"ref"});`

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete     EnumHeaderName
>     - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration

I'm sure it's something silly but any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JsonIgnoreProperties annotation is a Type annotation... it should go right above the interface definition line rather than in the body of the interface.

Like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"ref"});
interface CustomerSTatesIgnoreMixin {
```

Hope this helps.